# Turning on/off specific HDMI port on Pi 4

Tags: hdmi, pi-4, raspbian-buster

According to the [docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/vcgencmd.md), vcgencmd now can specify which hdmi port as a second argument for raspberry pi 4, so I did sudo apt update then sudo apt upgrade
but `vcgencmd display_power 0 7` returns `error=2 error_msg="Invalid arguments"`.

Comment: There seems some confusion in the docs.  Have you tried "$ tvservice -l" to get the two TV Ids and then try "@vcgencmd display_power X", where X is the id of the TV you want to power off?

Comment: yes it appears that they have updated the docs before the push made it to stable, however, you can get the update using rpi-upgrade (proceed with caution), I don't think vcgencmd display_power X would work as you still need to specify the value 0 for off and 1 for on, but again still feature not in available yet in stable.